# looping though JSON data to populate HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the below JSON data and basically what i want to do is populate a few divs with the relevant HTML included in the array.

```
[{"id":"1","name":"profile title","html":"<h2 class=\"entry-title\" id=\"title\">Settings, Put something here?<\/h2>","typeId":"1"},
{"id":"2","name":"username","html":"<fieldset disabled><br><label for=\"nameinput\">Username<\/label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"'.$name.'\" ><\/fieldset><p>","typeId":"1"},
{"id":"3","name":"date of birth","html":"<label for=\"dob\">Date of birth<\/label><input type=\"text\" name=\"dob\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"01\/02\/2000\"><p>","typeId":"1"}]
```

Here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#profile").one("click",function(){  

                $.ajax( {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: ROOT+"controlpanel/profile",
                    dataType:"json",
                    success: function(data){   

                            $.each(data, function(id, data1) 
                             {

                                    $('#title').html(data1.html);
                                    $('#container').append(data1.html);  
                            });
                        }


        });
    });
});
```

The problem I have is that I would like the html in ID 1 to go in a different div to id 2.

Comment: Is every element in the array supposed to go to different divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#profile").one("click",function(){  
        $.ajax( {
            type: "GET",
            url: ROOT+"controlpanel/profile",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){   

                $.each(data, function(id, data1) 
                {
                    $('#title'+data.id).html(data1.html);
                    $('#container'+data.id).append(data1.html);  
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Of course, if your json array can be of arbitrary lenth, chances are that you don't yet have the elements to put the content in. You could build the html to hold your data inside the loop. Or you could use a hidden html template, and use `jquery.clone()` to copy it and then populate it in the loop. You could use `jquery.append()` to add all your pieces of html to the same container, possibly wrapped in a div. You could create a new element with `jquery('div', {})`, append that element somewhere and add your html to this new div.

There's tons of ways of handling this. I hope this helps you on your way. If you need more detailed advice, provide some more detail in your question.